# ActionBarCompat on Gingerbread fills whole screen

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-actionbar-compat

So we've successfully stripped ActionBarSherlock from the Zappos app in favor of the new ActionBarCompat and it works great on Honeycomb+ but on Gingerbread the action bar expands to fill the whole screen and I cannot figure out why it's happening. We basically just changed all the themes/styles/references to ActionBarSherlock to be the equivalents in ActionBarCompat. Below is a screen shot of the issue. Anyone else run across this on GB and know of a fix? It's holding up a release for us :\

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have custom views in the actionbar. What happens when you set their height to wrap_content?

Answer (score 5):

Alright so I figured it out finally... we had copied the appcompat source code as a library project rather than using the com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+ dependency in gradle. After switching to the dependency in gradle and removing the appcompat source from our project it works as intended now.

Comment: Any idea on the root cause for this issue?  Removing the library project and adding as a maven-style artifact fixed my issue as well, but just wondering why that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's answer to the problem: http://gmariotti.blogspot.com.br/

It was just add this:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem where the actionbar filled the entire screen when I went from using ActionBar AppCombat to use ActionBarSherlock. In the value-v11 folder style.xml file. I had to remove the ActionBar Style there that inherit from the ActionBar appCombat.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. The issue was that my themes definitions for Gingerbread were pointing to a style that didn't exist.

I had this in `values/themes.xml`:

```
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/mytheme_solid_ActionBar</item>
```

But this `mytheme_solid_ActionBar` was only defined in `values-v11/styles.xml` and `values-v14/styles.xml`.

I just had to add it to `values/styles.xml` so that Gingerbread devices would have a proper style defined for the action bar (which inherits from `Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse`).

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the parent that my custom actionBarStyle was inheriting from.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/sfActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/sfActionBar</item>
</style>
```

My custom style was originally:

```
<style name="sfActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">...</style>
```

The change to get it to work on everything but Gingerbread was:

```
<style name="sfActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionBar">...</style>
```

The correct modification:

```
<style name="sfActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">...</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once I had similar issue (Toolbar's color filled the whole screen on Gingerbread) and the solution was to remove `android:clipChildren="false"` from the Toolbar's parent view.